# Tkinter treeview adding extra space on (0,0)

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

I am trying to make a treeview listing icons with no headings or text, but I cannot remove the empty space at the heading without my images disappearing.

```
#..implementation 
cols = ['A']
icon_tree = ttk.Treeview(gridroot, columns=cols, selectmode='none', height=14, show='tree')
icon_tree.column('A', anchor=CENTER, width=20)
icon_tree.heading('A', text="bruh2", anchor=CENTER)

#..setting up the grid objects
Lb.grid(column=1, row=2)
    Lb.config(font=lb_font, selectmode=MULTIPLE, height=len(process_list))
    Lb2.grid(column=2, row=2)
    Lb2.config(font=lb_font, selectmode=MULTIPLE, height=len(process_list))
    icon_tree.grid(column=0, row=2)
    get_time_btn.grid(column=1, row=3)
    rm_from_list_btn.grid(column=2, row=3)
    refresh_list_btn.grid(column=1, row=4)
    add_monitor_btn.grid(column=2, row=4)

#..how icons are added to the tree
i = get_icon(exe)
im = ImageTk.PhotoImage(i)
icons.append(im)
icon_tree.insert(parent='', index='end', image=icons[didx])
```

How it looks (it's supposed to line up with the listbox names):
[image]

Removing the heading doesn't seem to make a difference. Doing `show=''` makes the images not appear on the screen.

Comment: Why don't you put the contents of the listbox into a column of the treeview? Then you don't need the listbox at all.

Comment: I need the listbox selection functionality though. Is there an equivalent for treeviews? @acw1668

Comment: Check the [official document on `ttk.Treeview`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tkinter.ttk.html#treeview).

Comment: I see. I will try to implement it with treeview then. I still don't know why the bugs are happening though.

Comment: It is because: 1) the row height of the treeview is not the same as the listbox (may be due to using different fonts); 2) the number of viewable rows of them are different (from the image, treeview is 14 and listbox is 15).  Even you fix the above issues, you still need to synchronise them when scrolling.